# Why is UIView moved to right on offsetBy

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have a scrollview with an UIImageView on it. When the user scrolls, I would like to keep the UIImageView at its original place. I am using offsetBy for this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    self.headerView!.currentLoadLabel.frame = currentLoadLabelFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offset)
}
```

The UIImageView stays at his y position but moves to the farmost x position at the right of the screen. Why?

Answer (score 0):

try following code:
self.headerView!.currentLoadLabel.frame = currentLoadLabelFrame.offsetBy(dx:  scrollView.contentOffset.x, dy:  scrollView.contentOffset.y)